# Can you find 5 mistakes in this organic molecule?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

I found two:
1) the Oxygen needs a positive charge
2) the carbon on the far bottom has 5 bonds

Comment: 1) It's technically not incorrect because skeletal formulae do not necessarily carry information about geometry, but alkynes should be depicted linear 2) the chiral carbon has two substituents coming out of the plane, which makes no sense

Comment: I'm only finding four: your two and orthocresol's two. Are you sure there should be five?

Comment: No stereochemistry is given at the bridgehead carbons.  That's not really an error, but given that elsewhere in the molecule stereochemistry in indicated, maybe that's the fifth "error"?

Comment: Tertiary alcohol, both the Methyl and Alcohol are both marked in bold. One should be hashed.

Answer (score 1):

The five mistakes are:

1. Oxygen in the 5-member ring needs a positive charge [mentioned]
2. Carbon at the bottom should be a methylene, not methyl [mentioned]
3. Alkyne Group is not drawn in a linear fashion [mentioned in comments]
4. Carbon with $3^o$ alcohol has two substituents going out of the plane [mentioned in comments]
5. Chiral Carbon to the left of the oxygen in the 5-member ring has no stereochemistry indicated.

Now, 5 is not technically wrong but since the rest of the molecule is labelled for stereochemistry it is odd that this chiral center is not marked.

Comment: Something that could be one of the 5 but is not wrong per se is the =CH- in the middle. Similar carbons in the rest of the structure are assumed.

Comment: I would consider ignoring the stereochemistry wrong.  In addition to the stereocenter to the left of the oxygen, the carbons at the ring fusion are undefined stereocenters.